# Short-length science fiction comeback since 2017/2018?

Tags: history-of-literature, genre

Has there been a resurgence of short literary science fiction novels since late 2017 or early 2018? "Short" here refers to works as at most 200 pages. Literary science fiction is science fiction draws attention to its prose, is likely more character-based, and doesn't rely on tropes as much as its commercial counterpart.

Are there any data (sales, authors publishing more shorter works, reader preferences, ...)?

Comment: What do you mean by "literary science fiction" as opposed to "science fiction" without the qualification "literary"?

Comment: Science fiction we know. Literary fiction draws attention to its prose, likely to be more character-based, and doesn't rely on tropes as much as its commercial counterpart.